# With CSS3, how should we use the new unit vh, vw, and with the body margin considered?

Tags: css, viewport, viewport-units

In CSS3, there are these 2 new units: `vh` and `vw`.  So we can use

```
height: 80vh;
width: 60vw;
```

to scale a block that is 80 percent viewport height, or 60 percent viewport width.

But I think typically, the default `body` element has a `8px` margin at all 4 sides, so how should we incorporate this into our use of `vw`, and `vh` if we do need to use `100vh` and `100vw` (or almost that amount to cover up the width and height, but work with the body's margin)?  Some options include (1) resetting body margin to `0`, (2) resetting body margin to `8px` (so to make sure it is the same across all browsers (3) use `height: calc(100vh - 8px)` and `width: calc(100vw - 16px)` to set the proper height and width... but the `8px` and `16px` seem too hardcoded.  What might be good practices to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

**(4) You have to define the body margin using `vh` and `vm` unit.**

```
body {
   margin: 0.5vh 0.5vw;
}

.content {
  width: 99vw;
  height: 99vh;
}
```

It's the only way to be sure to have 100% of the viewport height and width.

Comment: interesting solution... although if width of the viewport is 1000px, then I kind of expect the margin to have that 8px value already, or else it may be too little, so maybe your solution can just be 0.8vw and content width 98.4vw

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the `body` element to 0 seems like the easiest and most efficient solution.

Comment: but what about other elements on the page?  then they need to have a `margin: 8px` when they want a margin as usual?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Yes they do, or don't reset and set a negative margin on the ones which needs to cover full width. Either way, this might tell you there is no good practice, only different good based on requirements.

Comment: no, I am not saying I want full width.  I am saying I want the full width except for the body's left and right margin.  I suppose we can say: no good practice (yet).  As things evolve, it may be that almost all modern browsers have a margin 8px at all four sides for the body, so it is safe to assume 8px, or put it as a variable in your SASS